# Если Git заменяет LF на CRLF при коммите, заменит ли он их обратно, если я сделаю git pull?

Tags: unity3d, git

У меня есть проект на Unity и некоторые файлы почему-то имеют окончание строк LF. В связи с этим я получаю предупреждения вида

```
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory. warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in [Имя файла]
```

когда делаю git commit.
И пока я делаю только push в удаленный репозиторий, это нормально. Но что будет если кто-то другой присоединится и что-то изменит, а я потом синхронизируюсь с репозиторием? Останутся ли у меня LF или заменятся на CRLF? И как на это отреагирует Unity? Я прочитал много других вопросов на эту тему, но ответа на свой так и не нашел.

Comment: проверить-то несложно.

Comment: не хотелось бы, чтобы всё поломалось.. я с юнити плохо знаком, боюсь, поломаю что-то в проекте